# How to move multiple objects to central point

Tags: objects, edges, axis

I'm trying to move multiples objects next to the central point but without success is there anyway to do it without doing one by one but all objects at once ? (`Not using scaling up and down`)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [*"Push/Pull"* operation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/transform/push_pull.html#push-pull):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can enable the *Transform > Affect Only > Locations* option:

[image]

Make sure that you have the right *Pivot Point* enabled, in your case maybe *3D Cursor* once you've put it at the center with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>:

[image]

[image]