# How to scale the distance between objects, without affecting their individual scales?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

This is a case study I'm constantly up against and figured I would ask if there is a shortcut:

I have two objects in my scene.  I want to move them away from each other along the same axis (x, for instance).  I could simply move them individually, one in the positive and the other in the negative direction, but it would be amazing if it was possible to just use the Scale tool and actually just scale the distance between them.

If you select both objects and scale along the X axis, it does push them apart but it also distorts them.  Is there a way to do this without affecting their scales?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200937/how-to-move-multiple-objects-to-central-point/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8892/is-there-a-way-to-rotate-the-origin-without-rotating-the-geometry/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154340/where-is-the-manipulate-centers-only-button-in-blender-2-8/

Comment: Great, thanks. I searched but those links didn’t show up, must have been using the wrong search terms.